# How to rename column names from lookup in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have metadata in my Azure SQL db /csv file as below which has old column name and datatypes and new column names.
[image]

I want to rename and change the data type of oldfieldname based on those metadata in ADF.

The idea is to store the metadata file in cache and use this in lookup but I am not able to do it in data flow expression builder. Any idea which transform or how I should do it?

Comment: In case if no output is returned, you need to use script task for that rather than lookup activity

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and able to change the column names and datatypes like below.

This is the sample csv file I have taken from blob storage which has meta data of table.

In your case, take care of new Data types because if we don't give correct types, it will generate error because of the data inside table.

[image]

Create dataset and give this to lookup and don't check first row option.

[image]

This is my sample SQL table:

[image]

Give the lookup output array to ForEach.

[image]

Inside ForEach use script activity to execute the script for changing column name and Datatype.

[image]

**Script:**

```
EXEC SP_RENAME 'mytable2.@{item().OldName}', '@{item().NewName}', 'COLUMN';

ALTER TABLE mytable2
ALTER COLUMN @{item().NewName} @{item().Newtype};
```

Execute this and below is my SQL table with changes.

[image]

Comment: I can't see the images. Can you post it again?

Comment: I have checked. There is no problem from my end. Could you please reload and check from your end.